# How can I assign a class to a number_to_percentage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4, percentage

I have the following code:

```
<%= number_to_percentage(a.number, precision: 1) %>
```

How can I give that element a class or id?

```
<%= number_to_percentage(a.number, precision: 1), class: "number" %>
```

returns an error and

```
<%= number_to_percentage(a.number, precision: 1, class: "number") %>
```

doesn't do anything at all. I also don't want to wrap it in a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number_to_percentage` doesn't return a tag. It returns a simple string. If you want to wrap it in a tag with a class, you need to do that manually:

```
<div class="number"><%= number_to_percentage(a.number, precision: 1) %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [number_to_percentage docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_percentage), there is no option for `class` or `id`, you'll have to wrap it in a span or a div.

Answer (score 0):

For your view you can write a helper method. They are very useful to keep you code dry.

In your application_helper.rb

```
def fancy_percentage(number, precision, options={}) 
  content_tag(:div, number_to_percentage(number, precision: precision), options)
end
```

"options" will remain empty until you use it for something ex. `id: 'something'`

So you can use it like this in your view:

```
<%= fancy_percentage(a.number, 1, id: 'something_particular', class: 'number' ) %>
```

I'd say this is pretty flexible solution. I use it all the time.